# Filter listview with data from mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, listview

I am trying to change the `private void displayListView()` of this tutorial (http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html) so I can check if it would still work if I get the data from mySql database instead.

Here's the Json Array from my PHP file:

```
[{"code":"AFG","name":"Afghanistan","continent":"Asia","region":"Southern and Central Asia"},    {"code":"ALB","name":"Albania","continent":"Europe","region":"Southern Europe"},{"code":"DZA","name":"Algeria","continent":"Africa","region":"Northern Africa"},{"code":"ASM","name":"American Samoa","continent":"Oceania","region":"Polynesia"},{"code":"AND","name":"Andorra","continent":"Europe","region":"Southern Europe"},{"code":"AGO","name":"Angola","continent":"Africa","region":"Central Africa"},{"code":"AIA","name":"Anguilla","continent":"North America","region":"Caribbean"}]
```

Here's what I did:

```
private void displayListView() {
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Country country = new Country(code, name, continent, region);
                                country.setCode(obj.getString("code"));
                                country.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                country.setContinent(obj.getString("continent"));
                                country.setRegion(obj.getString("region"));

                                // adding country to country array
                                countryList.add(country);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

But I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

I am not sure if I am parsing JSON the right way, and I can't figure the error out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not getting any data in response in your app from php. Try to log your received result from service call and then pass for parsing.